# Invalid Syntax on Python if statement

Tags: python

I have recently started using Python and I was typing out a simple code when I got an Invalid syntax error does anyone understand where I went wrong?

```
Swansea= 2

Liverpool= 2

If Swansea < Liverpool:
    print("Swansea beat Liverpool")

If Swansea > Liverpool:
    print("Liverpool beat Swansea")

If Swansea = Liverpool:
    print("Swansea and Liverpool drew")
```

The word "Swansea" becomes highlighted in red

Comment: Another point that doesn't relate to your syntax error, is that when you are comparing with `<`,`>`,and `==`, there is only one possible answer. A number can't be `<` and `>` and `==` another number. So it would make more sense to you the `if x > y: .... elif y > x: ... else: ....` construct. It makes more sense semantically and also only executes *one* of the blocks each time not 3.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems:

1. You need to use `==` for comparison tests, not `=` (which is for variable assignment).
2. `if` needs to be lowercase.  Remember that Python is case-sensitive.

However, you *should* be using `elif` and `else` here since no two of those expressions could ever be `True` at the same time:

```
Swansea=2

Liverpool=2

if Swansea < Liverpool:
    print("Swansea beat Liverpool")

elif Swansea > Liverpool:
    print("Liverpool beat Swansea")

else:
    print("Swansea and Liverpool drew")
```

Though using three separate `if`'s won't generate an error, using `elif` and `else` is much better for two reasons:

1. Code clarity: It is a lot easier to see that only *one* of the expressions will ever be `True`.
2. Code efficiency: Evaluation will stop as soon as an expression is `True`.  Your current code however will always evaluate *all three* expressions, even if the first or the second is `True`.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting the syntax error because of all the `If` they need to be lower case `if`. Also the equality operator is `==` not `=`

```
if Swansea == Liverpool: 
     print("Swansea and Liverpool drew")
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive so probably `If` is raising invalid syntax. Should be `if`.